# Информационная ёмкость русского слова

Tags: общие-вопросы, недопустимая-метка

Возможно ли в принципе точное значение знания за каждой русской буквой, которое несёт точное внутреннее знание одного слова, как односмысла. Есть ли вообще в русском языке раздел знания о смысловом знании русских букв.

Comment: Сам русский язык есть триединство, как Азбука - алфавит есть определённый ряд букв, Букварь есть свод правил и законов простроения из букв слов (как односмыслов) и предложений, Буковица - это новое знание о русском языке, как понимание соотношения: одна буква - один простой не плавающий звук - один простой смысл - одно простое чувство. И понимание, что человек разговаривающий на русском языке в принципе сознательно или подсознательно воспринимает 33 чувства (не разбуженный экстрасенс). Возможно ли такое понимание о русском языке. Ознакомительная статья "Знаете ли вы родной русский язык".

Comment: В окне Поиск наберите »Алфавит» — увидите 33 рассуждения на эту тему.

Answer (score 1):

В русском языке как науке таких знаний нет(там только лексич. значение слова и информационная ёмкость текста, а о букве и звуке - в графике и фонетике  ), но в ведических знаниях сколько угодно, почитайте, если до сих пор не наткнулись на них и интересно:

http://russkieslogi.ru/znachenija-russkih-bukv.html
изыскания Беликова В. П.

http://rybkovskaya.ru/alfavit_azbuka/

http://wordgame.64g.ru/meta/meta2.htm

http://www.habit.ru/13/276.html

http://way-s.ru/viewtopic.php?f=93&t=3938 -сайт  Посейдона

Comment: А насчёт возможно-невозможно  -  я приверженец научных знаний, а не фантазий.

Comment: Прискорбно, уважаемая Людмила, что вы приверженец точных научных знаний. Вот только кто в этом мире присваивает звание "учёный", если это научный совет, то мне вас жалко в двойне, так как ту же науку двигают молодые, а тот же совет звание "учёный" раздаёт старым и увешанным регалиями. Вы сейчас присутствуете при появлении нового знания о русском языке, и это полное знание о русском языке, которое всё равно будет утверждаться в мире русского человека даже вопреки мнениям маститых учёных от науки (и вашему мнению тоже).     Толька ветер.